# When I deploy the application Nodejs with Markojs at google cloud app engine, I receive the error "EROFS: read-only file system...'"

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, marko

I'm new in Google Cloud Resources.

I'm deploying a Nodejs(with Markojs) application at google cloud's app engine and I'm getting the error "EROFS: read-only file system, open '/srv/src/app/converter/form/.7.1565968890124.converter.marko.js'"

At Google documentaion is said "Filesystem
The runtime includes a full filesystem. The filesystem is read-only except for the location /tmp, which is a virtual disk storing data in your App Engine instance's RAM."

Link: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#filesystem

I ran "echo $PATH" from "Production environment" and I got "/srv/node_modules/.bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

I'm trying set up the environment variable "PATH" in order to fix the path "/srv/.node_modules to /tmp/.node_modules". I don't know whether it'll fix the problem.

On app.yaml file I wrote,

```
#   Copyright 2018, Google LLC.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
# [START runtime]
runtime: nodejs10

env_variables:
  ## Put production environment variables here.
  ## PATH: /tmp/node_modules/.bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  PATH: /tmp/node_modules/.bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  _: /tmp
  HOME: /tmp
```

The full error is:

Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/srv/src/app/converter/form/.7.1565968890124.converter.marko.js'      at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)      at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1194:35)      at
 compile (/srv/node_modules/marko/dist/node-require/index.js:61:16)      at Object.markoRequireExtension [as .marko] (/srv/node_modules/marko/dist/node-require/index.js:115:27)      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)      at
 tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Bin2DecView.get template [as template] (/srv/src/app/converter/Bin2DecView.js:9:16)

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `marko/node-require` hook writes to the filesystem by default, but you can configure this:

```
require("marko/node-require").install({
  writeToDisk: false
});
```

[src/compiler/config.js#L32-L37](https://github.com/marko-js/marko/blob/701c26486cd288773f15eba74a6723fea21f8d94/src/compiler/config.js#L32-L37)

Comment: Thank you so much! In a first moment I did this configuration and at first didn't work. So I had to remove folder node_module and "npm install" again and then worked!